# How to iterate over my class

Tags: c#

I have two classes named `Person` and `Staff`. `Person` class just keeps fields and properties. `Staff` class implements `IEnumarable` interface. What I want to do is to make this class enumarable. I will create an instance  `Staff` class on `form_Load` and then iterate over it. But I think something is wrong here.

```
 public Person this[int index]
    {
        get { return Staff[index]; }
        set { Staff[index] = value; }
    }
```

This is what I have so far. How can I fix this

```
public class Person
{
    private int _age;
    private string _name;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public Person(int age, string name)
    {
        _age = age;
        _name = name;
    }
}

public class Staff : IEnumerable
{
    private List<Person> list;

    public Person this[int index]
    {
        get { return Staff[index]; }
        set { Staff[index] = value; }
    }

    public Staff(Person person)
    {
        list = new List<Person>();
        list.Add(person);
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return list[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix what? Do you get any compile time errors? Does code not do what you want? Something else?

Comment: Why not `IEnumerable<Person>`?

Comment: `Staff(Person person)` should be split into two methods. One initializing the list (the constructor) and one adding persons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax errors indeed. This would work though:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var staff = new Staff();
        staff.AddPerson(new Person(12, "John Doe"));
        staff.AddPerson(new Person(12, "Jande Doe"));

        foreach (var person in staff)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Person(int age, string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}

public class Staff : IEnumerable<Person>
{
    private List<Person> staff = new List<Person>();

    public void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        this.staff.Add(p);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.staff.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.staff.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I'm getting the impression that you want to enumerate the collection of persons through the staff class. You can do that by implementing IEnumerable and return the enumerator of the people list. So that's what I did.
I implemented IEnumerable to return a strongly typed enumerator and shortened some of your code. Hope it helps.